# Swift 3.1 Label in TableViewCell - unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift3, uitableview

I'm trying to create two tableViews in one UIViewController. But when I'm trying to assign value to UILabel, getting an error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I wonder why, I have almost the same code for TableViewController with one tableView and it works with no issues. It looks like these UI Labels are not initialized when trying to assign value to it. But don't understand how to fix it.

It fails here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    if tableView == self.guestsTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestAtTableTableViewCell
        if let guestsTable = guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) {
            print(guestsTable.guestName) // works fine, prints the value
            print(cell.guestNameLabel.text) //fails here with error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            cell.guestNameLabel.text = guestsTable.guestName
            cell.openTimeLabel.text = String(describing: guestsTable.openTime)
            cell.cellDelegate = self
        }
    }
    else if tableView == self.ordersTableView {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "orderCell", for: indexPath)
        //to be done
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell!
}
```

Full code of this class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableUIViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CellWithButtonDelegate {
    //The following two variables will not be nil because prepare for segue will set them
    var tableName: String?
    var table: TablesTable? = nil

    fileprivate var currentTableSession: TableSessionTable? {
        get {
            let tableSessionTable = TableSessionTable()
            return tableSessionTable.getCurrentTableSession(table: table!)
        }
    }
    fileprivate var guestsTableFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<GuestsTable>?
    fileprivate var ordersTableFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<OrdersTable>?

    @IBOutlet weak var tableNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableCapacityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableCountOfGuestsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableDescriptionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBAction func closeTableButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var guestsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ordersTableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func addGuestButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let guestsTable = GuestsTable()
        let tablesTable = TablesTable()
        let table = Table(tableName: tableName!, tableCapacity: 0, locationX: nil, locationY: nil, tableImage: nil)
        try? guestsTable.addNewGuest(table: tablesTable.getOrCreateTable(table: table))
        updateUI()
    }
    @IBAction func addOrderButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        guestsTableView.dataSource = self
        guestsTableView.delegate = self
        guestsTableView.register(GuestAtTableTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "guestCell")

        ordersTableView.dataSource = self
        ordersTableView.delegate = self
        ordersTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "orderCell")
        updateUI()
    }

    func didPressButton(table: TablesTable) {
    }


    private func updateUI () {
        let tableView = guestsTableView
        let context = AppDelegate.viewContext
        let request : NSFetchRequest<GuestsTable> = GuestsTable.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "table= %@", currentTableSession!)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "guestName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))]
        guestsTableFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<GuestsTable>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        try? guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }

    private func updateUI1 () {
        let tableView = ordersTableView
        let context = AppDelegate.viewContext
        let request : NSFetchRequest<OrdersTable> = OrdersTable.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "menuItem", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))]
        ordersTableFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<OrdersTable>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        try? ordersTableFetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell?
        if tableView == self.guestsTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestAtTableTableViewCell
            if let guestsTable = guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) {
                print(guestsTable.guestName) // works fine, prints the value
                print(cell.guestNameLabel.text) //fails here with error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
                cell.guestNameLabel.text = guestsTable.guestName
                cell.openTimeLabel.text = String(describing: guestsTable.openTime)
                cell.cellDelegate = self
            }
        }
        else if tableView == self.ordersTableView {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "orderCell", for: indexPath)
            //to be done
        }
        // Configure the cell...
        return cell!
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.guestsTableView {
            return guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 1
        }
        else if tableView == self.ordersTableView {
            return ordersTableFetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 1
        }
        else {return 1}
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.guestsTableView {
            if let sections = guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
                return sections[section].numberOfObjects
            }
            else {
                return 0
            }
        }
        else if tableView == self.ordersTableView {
            if let sections = ordersTableFetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
                return sections[section].numberOfObjects
            }
            else {
                return 0
            }
        }
        else {return 0}
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if tableView == self.guestsTableView {
            if let sections = guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
                return sections[section].name
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        else if tableView == self.ordersTableView {
            if let sections = ordersTableFetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
                return sections[section].name
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        else {return nil}

    }

    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        if tableView == guestsTableView {
            return guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.sectionIndexTitles
        }
        else {
            return ordersTableFetchedResultsController?.sectionIndexTitles
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == guestsTableView {
            return guestsTableFetchedResultsController?.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index) ?? 0
        }
        else if tableView == ordersTableView {
            return ordersTableFetchedResultsController?.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index) ?? 0
        }
        else {return 0}
    }
}
```

And full code of UITableViewCell class:

```
import UIKit

class GuestAtTableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var cellDelegate: CellWithButtonDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var guestNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var openTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func didPressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reconnecting the IBOutlet of UILabel.

Comment: Tried, but didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have a xib for your UITableViewCell register the xib instead of the class.
Use the following:

```
guestsTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "GuestAtTableTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "guestCell")
```

As you have created a prototype cell in the storyboard itself you should select the cell in the storyboard and set its identifier there. Next remove the register line from your code for guestCell. It should work

Comment: Thanks, but I have no xib for this cell. I have tried anyway your line and got:Could not load NIB in bundle. :(

Comment: Your cell has class has IBOutlet?? I edited my answer in case there is not outlet

Comment: Yep, kindly check the last code listing in my post.

Comment: I have rechecked your update. Can you please advise how should I do it? Didn't get it :(

Comment: Can you tell where have you set the IBOutlets if you don't have a xib for it?

Comment: I have declared them in this class: class GuestAtTableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell (last listing). I've put labels into cell prototype of tableView in StoryBoard.

Comment: Yes! You are absolutely right. I used this example to create my code: https://gist.github.com/mchirico/50cdb07d20b1b0f73d7c and I missed that difference. So I have removed this line: guestsTableView.register(GuestAtTableTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "guestCell") and it started to work! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: it would be great if you could accept/upvote the answer.